# Jnetpcap: installation error

Tags: java, eclipse, jnetpcap

I've troubles installing jnetpcap in ubuntu/eclipse!!
I've downloaded following files:

- jnetcap-1.3.b3-1
- jnetcap-javadox-1.3.b3-1
- jnetcap-src-1.3.b3-1

Copied libjnetpcap.1.3.b3 to `/usr/lib`, build my `.jar` file in eclipse and
when I try to run it, I get the error:

> UnsatisfiedLinkError
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jnetpcap
>   in java.library.path

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but on Cent OS. This error appears when you try to use `jnetpcap` without having installed native library (libpcap.so) in the OS or some of its dependencies.

- Try to install native library using this [jnetpcatdoc](http://jnetpcap.com/?q=compile/debian) (it worked for me).
- Or just download appropriate library and specify path to it using `-Djava.library.path=/your path to lib/libpcap.so`.